# Creating a computed column in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

I'm having trouble creating a computed column in MSSQL. I'm using 2012, but ideally this would work with anything 2005 and on.
I need to set a column to be equal to 1% of another column for each month since the start date.
Here's what I have so far. I've tried entering this into the formula property of the computed column, but MSSQL says "There is an error with your forumla".

```
CASE 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LienStartDate, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(yyyy, LienStartDate, GETDATE()) * 365) >= 0 
    THEN Amount * (DATEDIFF(m, LienSTartDate, GETDATE()) * 0.01) 
  WHEN DATEDIFF(d, LienStartDate, GETDATE()) - (DATEDIFF(yyyy, LienStartDate, GETDATE()) * 365) < 0 
    THEN Amount * ((DATEDIFF(m, LienStartDate, GETDATE()) - 1) * 0.01) END
```

When I run it against the following data as a select I get back the correct results. (12, 11, 12)

```
LienStartDate | Amount
2014/01/20      100
2014/01/25      100
2014/01/23      100
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the statement that is causing the error -- either a `create table ` or `alter table` statement.

Comment: I'm doing it in the visual designer.

Comment: Stop doing that. The visual designers are an atrocity. Also, please stop using lazy shorthand. What is the benefit of `yyyy` when you could have typed the more explicit `year`? Did typing `d` instead of `day` boost productivity? Please read this: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx and #6 here: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-wrong-optimizations/

Comment: @AaronBertrand, totally fair. I'm currently trying to figure out how to do it in a script.

Comment: It's really about as easy as pointing and clicking your way into the designer: `ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD bar AS (<formula>);`

Comment: ...and if there is a problem trying to execute that, you will probably get a much more helpful error message than "there is an error in your formula."

Comment: @AaronBertrand: wow, take it down a notch.  You're barking orders in drive-by comments that don't address the question.  This is unlikely to help anyone, or convince people to do things your way.

Comment: @Ned ok, thanks for the advice. These are problems I see daily (which is why I blog about them) and I'm not going to spend half an hour crafting a custom "play nice" message every time they come up. The OP even said my comment was fair, so I'm not sure why *you* need to be over-sensitive about it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand. All I needed was ALTER TABLE dbo.foo ADD bar AS (<formula>). That made it work perfectly.

Comment: So another reason to avoid the visual designers. Glad it was an easy fix.